# Terraria house building

Tags: terraria

My house is big enough I followed all instructions but it still won't work. I tried making it 7x5 but NPC's still won't move in.

Is it because the house is made of dirt, mud, bricks, and stone? How do I get NPC's to move into my house?

Comment: Is the question about Terraria or Minecraft? You mention the former in the title, the latter in the tags, and neither in the actual question.

Comment: Did you try to use the housing query? That tells you the exact problem. And can you add a screenshot? Can't do much to help you if we can't see the problem.

Comment: Did you add a chair and a table?

Answer (score 0):

Did you remember to add the background walls? Naturally generated ones don't count.

Comment: Yes I did and used uv torches